# The FAQ lists disallowed questions awkwardly.

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, site-faq

Essentially, the FAQ is listing questions that we should **not** be asking on this site in the **What kind of questions can I ask here?** heading.  Directly below that is the **What kind of questions should I *not* ask here?** heading.

This is rather confusing.  Shouldn't we list what questions not to ask in the section specifically designated for that information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We cannot modify the section entitled "What questions should I *not* ask here". This section is meant not to specify what is off-topic for the site, but off-topic for the network as a whole. The only section we are permitted to modify is the topmost section.

This format of listing the acceptable and then a break for the unacceptable is similar to how it is written on other sites such as [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq) and [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/faq). There is a variety of methods we can use to do it - ours is closer to Web Applications where we just use emphasis, while Seasoned Advice just adds a new heading (which, while viable, I felt kinda broke things up when I tried it here previously).

I'm open to suggestions on better formatting to help distinguish which list is acceptable and which isn't, but let's just keep it solid in mind that we *cannot* add to the second section. Only the first.

Comment: I did not realize this.  Now the decision for why it's designed the way it is makes sense.

Comment: @Strix We did publish the link to the [FAQ revision history](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/7147/revisions) multiple times now, I thought you'd know by now :)

Answer (score 1):

The list items are placed where they're intended to, as you might have guessed. You can see our FAQ drafting efforts in another meta question.

If you think a type of question listed in there should not be allowed, please make a separate, and specific meta question about it :)

Comment: I don't understand how you reached the conclusion to include information under a misleading heading.  Could you link to that meta topic or perhaps discuss further?  I do not want to change the content of the FAQ; I just feel like listing illegal questions in the "allowed questions" section is rather silly.

Comment: @Strix How about now? I added a newline and some emphasis on "prohibit".

Comment: Not really.  Let's say I'm a new user who decides (miraculously) to read the FAQ.  I'm not going to study it; I'm just going to skim it.  I see the heading **allowed questions** and a couple bulleted lists.  I'm probably going to draw the wrong conclusion.

Comment: This does make it a lot better given Grace's extra information.